# $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

**$\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$?**

I know this is false but I can not give a valid argument to justify this, why can not this be given? Thank you very much.

Comment: cardinality${}$?

Answer (score 12):

The set of algebraic numbers is countable, the set of complex numbers is uncountable. Therefore, there cannot be a bijection between them.

Comment: To be more explicit, $\bar Q$ contains precisely all the algebraic numbers, and there are plenty of transcendental real (and complex) numbers.

Comment: Also, the algebraic numbers are countable because you have a countable number of polynomials (you write them with finite combinations of symbols from a finite alphabet) and each polynomial has a finite number of roots.

Comment: @TedShifrin Won't we use the cardinality of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ to show existence of transcendental (non-algebraic) complex numbers ?

Comment: By all means, @reuns, uncountability of $\Bbb R$ shows the existence of transcendentals. And plenty of’em. But with a number sitting in your palm, you need a proof to show that it’s transcendental.

Answer (score 4):

No:

$\mathbb C$ contains $\pi$, which is transcendental over $\mathbb Q$.

$\overline {\mathbb Q}$ contains only elements that are algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.